# How can I integrate stripe in an app with kivy/python being on the client side (and python aswell on the server side)?

Tags: python, kivy, stripe-payments, kivymd

I am building a mobile app using **kivy/kivymd** and I am currently trying to **integrate Stripe payment** into the application. However, I have found that all the documentation on integrating Stripe with python considers python being the backend/ server side language of use and either kotlin (for android) or js, html, etc for the frontend/client side.

Hence, my issue, the client side of the app is written in kivy which is a framework based in python for cross-platform apps, however I have not found documentation on implementing the client side in python with stripe. If anyone has any idea on how to do so or any guidance, I'll be very grateful. Thank you in advance.

PS: I have thought about creating a website or using their payment links as a lazy way to get around this, however I have not found luck with the **"WebView"** in kivy as it didn't work with me so that's out of the way.